# Why I could not reorder my custom post type?

Tags: wordpress

I tried lots of custom codes for same also I used the https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/ plugin for reorder my posts but posts are not displayed in reorder.

Can anyone help me to find out the solution for same?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/ & some custom codes

```
'orderby'        => 'menu_order', 
'order'          => 'DESC',
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'enter your cpt name here',
'order'=>'DSC',
'posts_per_page' => 5
) );
?>
```

enter your custom post type name in the post type, it will work, copy the same code and paste wherever you want to display in UI, change post per page as per your need.